# Firefox cache key name start with anon&uri=http://xxxx

Tags: javascript, rest, firefox, caching, xmlhttprequest

I tried to access a resource on a REST server by XHR, because of I want to download it.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function iframe_onload (){

     var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     var url = "http://example.com/document/12345"

     xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("accept","application/pdf");

     xmlhttp.onload = function() {

     var oIFrm = document.getElementById('myIFrm');
     oIFrm.src = url; 

    };

    xmlhttp.send(null);
   }


<iframe id="myIFrm"  style="visibility:hidden" src="">  
</iframe>
```

it's working on Chrome, Safari, IE but just not working on FF, I checked the cache in FF, the first request from XHR is start with "anon&uri", so the cache key is like "anon&uri=http://example.com/document/12345", and the current page and the url is not in same domain, and I have setup CORS for server,  and then the second request canont get PDF file from cache, and if I put 2 server under same domain, the cache key is a normal one without "anon&uri", then code is working.

Anybody have idea why the cache key is start with "anon&uri=" when I setup CORS for both server on FF, and how to avoid this problem and make the code working.

Thanks,

Joey

Answer (score 0):

You can append a timestamp at the end of the url, so that the page is not cached:

```
var now=Date();
var heartbeat=now.getTime();
oIFrm.src = url+'?'+heartbeat;
```

Also change onload to onreadystatechange:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    var now=Date();
    var heartbeat=now.getTime();
    var oIFrm = document.getElementById('myIFrm');
    oIFrm.src = url+'?'+heartbeat;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cache key starts with "anon&" because it's an anonymous (no cookies, no http auth allowed) request and hence shouldn't be cached in the same cache entry as a normal request for the same URI.

You can't do what you're trying to do here while having a sane cache behavior in general.